# Firebase Hosting multiple subdomains to app directories with 1 project

Tags: firebase, dns, subdomain, firebase-hosting

I currently have an app deployed to Firebase hosting with the following structure:

```
public/
    appSub1/
        index.html
    appSub2
        index.html
    index.html
```

I have already added and connected my subdomains such that

```
appSub1.mysite.com/ -> app.firebaseapp.com/
appSub2.mysite.com/ -> app.firebaseapp.com/
```

I am trying to configure the redirects to properly associate the subdomains with the correct app subfolder such that

```
appSub1.mysite.com/ -> app.firebaseapp.com/appSub1/
appSub2.mysite.com/ -> app.firebaseapp.com/appSub2/
```

The app is still correctly displayed if I manually add the sub paths, but not without them. So going to `appSub1.mysite.com/` just ends up at a blank page, but going to `appSub1.mysite.com/appSub1/` ends up at the correct `index.html`

This is my current hosting configuration in `firebase.json`

```
"hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "appSub1.mysite.com/**",
        "destination": "/appSub1/**",
        "type": 301
      },
      {
        "source": "appSub2.mysite.com/**",
        "destination": "/appSub2/**",
        "type": 301
      }
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the following:

1. Upgrade to Blaze plan on Firebase
2. Use Firebase Multi-site Hosting method (refer: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites)
3. Break `public/app1` and `public/app2` into two separate hosting project targets - say `app1` and `app2` - thus, by default the hosting address would be `app1.firebaseapp.com` and `app2.firebaseapp.com` (or now as of May 2019, you'll get a `.web.app` domain as well - `app1.web.app`
4. Connect individual subdomains by configuring DNS entries on your domain registry (refer: https://medium.com/@fransandi/use-firebase-multisite-hosting-to-associate-multiple-domains-subdomains-to-your-project-ee099109bfe9)

Comment: Then I would have two projects but this is just one. Different portals into the same database.

Comment: It'd still be one project (same projectId), same database. It is just multi site hosting on a single project in firebase. You need not have two projects.